# What can we do about offensive and worthless posts? (Was: How did this user/answer get access?)

Tags: discussion

Pretty disappointing that someone would use this site in this fashion. Is there a way to block this type of activity:

[Problem with congruence relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283755/problem-with-congruence-relations)

[Edit: This was in reference to an answer that is now deleted.]

Comment: "Is there a way to block this type of activity[?]" Do you have in mind something like not allowing certain language in posts?  Generally there is no way for the system to detect worthless answers before they are posted.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't, but if users are aware of Qiaochu's directive, as I am now, this stuff would be gone quickly with minimal harm. This actually was not a worthless answer. It was offensive racist diatribe.

Comment: Sorry, I understated, let's say offensive posts. The question title makes me wonder about a complementary one, "How would a user/answer not get access?" Unless there is some automatic block of certain words (which I'm sure is possible, although I don't know if it would be effective or good), I don't know of a way. I agree that deleting as soon as possible afterward is good.

Comment: This question is somewhat confusing in retrospect.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Good idea to edit the title. When I first wrote it, it was real-time, and I did not know to flag it for the moderators, so it was more of an alert.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flag the moderators. The post has been deleted and the account has been destroyed.

Comment: Thanks. When I went back, saw it was done.

Comment: Qiaochu, why don't you please edit the answer anyway so 10K+ people don't have to suffer it?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I just edited the answer before seeing your comment. Hope it is fine.

Comment: @Marvis Thank you!

Comment: This makes me wonder: since the *destruction* of users is something intended for spammers and other such worthless people, should not it result in actual (hard) deletion of their content, as opposed to the usual soft deletion?

Comment: @5PM: there's no such thing as hard deletion. Besides, "intents" aside, any tool can be misused. I know y'all trust us moderators and all, but it strikes me as a bad idea to voluntarily give up checks and balances.

Comment: @Willie Account destruction has a pretty low reputation  cap (500?). Also, in the hypothetical scenario of a site's mod destroying my account against my will, I think I'd prefer it if my content was gone too. The alternative, of the site kicking me out but keeping my contributions, feels more disagreeable to me.

Comment: @5PM: the contents are soft-deleted. I don't see how it can be used to boost traffic, as google bots certainly don't have 10K on MSE. Besides, you've agreed to a CC license the minute you started posting to the site, so if you really would feel bummed about the policy, well, _caveat emptor_.

Comment: @Willie Good point, I was editing out that part right as you answered. Moot point anyway.

Comment: @5PM Accounts can be reconstructed almost completely, as the posts are not lost. It is a lot of work for an SE employee though, and you lose some badges and all profile information. And no moderator will use the destroy option on anything other than a spammer, or at least they won't stay a mod much longer after that.

Comment: @MadScientist I just upvoted your suggestion in the thread [Ability for mods to hard-delete a question or revisions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111754/ability-for-mods-to-hard-delete-a-question-or-revisions). As the number of 10K+ user keeps growing, soft-delete will become increasingly inadequate; some 10K+ SO users [already complained](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110535/hide-deleted-answers-with-certain-characteristics) about having to live with the trash they can't take out.